# Disconnect a user from a windows network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008

We're running a shared licensing tool for some software (SPSS) and a user who happens to be on the opposite side of the world has left their computer on, taking up one of our two licenses. Shockingly SPSS doesn't provide a way to disconnect a user from the licensing server, so I need to figure out the simplest way to boot them from the network, any idea?

I've tried restarting the licensing service as per IBM's suggestions, however they just auto-reconnect after a minute or two.

As a last resort I could remote desktop into their computer as Admin and either log them off or shut down their NIC, but this would not be ideal in this particular circumstance.

Any way to kick someone off / block connections that I'm not aware of?

Cheers.

Running WS2008R2 btw.

Comment: Have you tried adding a block rule for their IP to the Windows firewall? That, in combination with a license server restart should do it I suppose.

Comment: Use a remote task killer of your choice to shut down the client app/service/process taking up the license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing to get it working. Handy trick for other issues too I would assume.

Get THE_IP of the machine that you want to block.

From elevated cmd promt:

```
route add THE_IP mask 255.255.255.255 10.0.0.250 -p //Assuming 10.0.0.250 is nothingness
```

To remove the route, again from elevated cmd prompt

```
route delete THE_IP
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest thing to do would be to block them at the network level, either on a host-side firewall or hardware firewall.  Once they are no longer able to connect to the licensing server you can then restart it.